# How is 1 cubic decimeter equal to 1 liter; and 1000 cubic centimeters equal to 1 liter?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Am I cubing these units? If so how?

My thinking? A decimeter is $10^{-1} = 0.1 \mathrm{m}$, a centimeter is $10^{-2} = 0.01 \mathrm{m}$.

If 1 liter = 1 cubic decimeter, how can it also equal 1000 cubic centimeters when the two units are only separated by a factor of 10?

Can some one explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A decimeter is $10 \text{cm}$

so

$$(1\text{dm})^3 = (10\text{cm})^3 = 1000 \text{cm}^3 = 1 \text{L}$$

Note you are cubing not only the number 10 to get 1000 but also the unit.