# Computing the area of a square given different units

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a square with side length $10$cm. Then its area is  $10\times10cm^2=100cm^2=1m^2$. Equivalentally, I could say I have a square of side length $0.1m$, so I get its area to be $\frac{1}{100}m^2=1cm^2$. This is not an equivalent area. Why is this so?

Is it the case that if a given length is $0<\ell<1$, one should always convert to a unit for which $\ell\ge1$, as otherwise the computations give nonsense answers?

Comment: $1m^2=10000cm^2$  Imagine laying out two metersticks in an L shape and marking off all the little squares that are a $cm^2$.  There would be $100*100$ of them.  $10000cm^2$

Comment: Not a duplicate but This question: [How is 1 cubic decimeter =1 liter; and 1000 cubic centimeters equal to 1 liter?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/921475/86986) is related. Note $1m^2 = (100cm)^2 = 10000 cm^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is made in the part when you say $$100cm^2 = 1m^2$$

In fact, there are $100^2 = 10000$ square centimeters in one square meter. For example, if you would have a unit of length $k$, which is composed of two $bk$, i.e. your measure looks like this:

[image]

Now, if you have a square with a side of $1k$, then it looks like this:

[image]

meaning that for *every* $bk$ in one $k$, you have two square $bk$ in the square.

Similarly, if you would have $100 cm$ in one meter, you have, in one square meter, one hundred square centimeters for *every* centimeter in the meter, summing up to $100\cdot 100$ square centimeters in the whole square meter.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered quite well by turkeyhundt's comment, but you can also use dimensional analysis to see why one-hundredth of a square meter isn't one square centimeter:

$$\frac{1}{100}\,m^2 = 100 \left(\frac{1}{100} \,m\right)^2=100 \,cm^2 \neq \left(\frac{1}{100} \,m\right)^2$$